# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k$ converges for u_k decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Problem:**

$(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ and $u_n \to 0$,

$$u_{n+1} \le u_n, \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N} \\
  u_n \ge 0, \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}.$$

Define $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}u_k \ .$

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k$ converges, thus $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}u_k$ converges.

Hints: Define $r_n = s_{2n+1}$ and $q_n = s_{2n}$. Show that $r_n$ converges, and $q_n$ has the same limit converges.

> > **I did so:**

We claim there exists $ A\in\Bbb{R},$ so that $A\ge0,$ is the sum of  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k$.

There exists an $\epsilon$ in $\Bbb{N}$, there is a $N_{\epsilon} \in \Bbb{N}$ and for all $n\ge N_{\epsilon}\\$ 
is $$|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k - A| < |s_{2n+1} - A|< |s_{2n} - A| < |s_n - A| < \epsilon. \\\\$$

It's clear that $$ \ r_n = q_n - u_{2n+1} \\ $$ 
and $$-u_{2n+1}<0<\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon.$$

Then $$|r_n - A|=|q_n - u_{2n+1} -A| \le |q_n - A|+u_{2n+1}< \epsilon \\$$

so that  $$|q_n -A|< \epsilon - u_{2n+1}< \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$

This means  $q_n$ and $r_n$ have the same limit and are monotonically decreasing, therefore $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k$ converges to 0.

> > > **Did I right? If not, could you give me any hints to understand what is wrong, please? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I haven't read your proof in details but please check the wiki proof of [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Comment: @sciona I edited the post. And I also didn't read the wikipedia page because inside there is the answer of this problem.

Comment: The title is now misleading. The question is to show that a series converges, not that it converges to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

> $s_n = -u_1 + u_2 \mp ... \mp u_{n-1} \mp u_n$

Better to use $+$ or $-$ except at the end.  And for $q_n$ and $r_n$ you know the sign of the last term too.

> $\ldots\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u_k.$

You haven't really made a complete thought here.  What are the previous few lines supposed to tell you about this sum?

> **Hypothesis:** $ \exists A\in\Bbb{R}, \ A\ge0, r_n \to A$

In formal writeups, use English words to make your work more readable.  Symbols are better for board work and scratch paper.  So you might write this instead as

> > We claim there exists $A \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \geq 0$ and $r_n \to A$.

But you still haven't shown that.

> $\Rightarrow \exists\epsilon\in\Bbb{N}, \ \text{for $\forall n\ge N_{\epsilon}$ is $|r_n - A| < \epsilon$} \\ $.

This doesn't make sense either.  What I think you mean to say is:

> > (Therefore?) For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|r_n - A| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N_\epsilon$.

This would be true if $r_n \to A$, which you still haven't shown.

> Since $ \ r_n = q_n - u_{2n-1} \ $ follows that $|r_n - A|=|q_n - u_{2n+1} -A| \le |q_n - A|+u_{2n+1}< \epsilon $

You are trying to make the claim that $q_n \to A$ as well, so really you should start with $|q_n - A|$ on the left and use $|r_n - A| < \epsilon$ on the right.

You also need to use that $u_{2n+1} < \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  And then the sum would be $2\epsilon$.  So you could go back to the beginning and replace all the $\epsilon$s with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, or just not worry about it.  It depends on how rigorous your instructor wants you to be.

> It means that $ \ q_n \to 0 \ \text{since $A \ge 0$}$,

If $q_n\to0$ then the series converges to zero, and I don't think that's what you're trying to show.

> and so the hypothesis is demonstarted.

Again, you haven't said anything demonstrating whether $\{r_n\}$ converges.  What you have shown is (close to) a proof that if $r_n \to A$, then $q_n \to A$ as well.  This is true and part of the proof that the series converges.

Here is a hint for the part you are missing: is $\{q_n\}$ or $\{r_n\}$ monotone?

Comment: Thank you you was helpful. I think I understood the errors and edited my demonstration. Am I stil wrong?

Comment: You still haven't addressed whether $\{r_n\}$ converges.  I think it would be best if you sought out the help of your instructor.  StackExchange is good for some things, but maybe not extended tutoring.